# adding preview sample for each track

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please i had problem to access the "preview_url"  from spotify api to add to my feature application . my application work fine but this challenge of including preview sample for each tracks don't work there is the mains files project :

the app.js file :

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import SearchResults from "../SearchResults/SearchResults";
import Playlist from "../Playlist/Playlist";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar/SearchBar";
import Spotify from "../../util/spotify";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [{name:"FirstSong", artist:"artistName", album:"album1", id:1}, {name:"secondSong", artist:"artistName", album:"album1", id:2}, 
      {name:"thirdSong", artist:"artistName", album:"album1", id:3}],
      playlistName: "My Playlist",
      playlistTracks: [{name:"fourthSong", artist:"artistName2", album:"album1", id:4}, {name:"fifthSong", artist:"artistName2", album:"album1", id:5}, 
      {name:"sixthSong", artist:"artistName2", album:"album1", id:6}],
    }
    this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
    this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
    this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
    this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
   }

  search (term) {
    Spotify.search(term).then(result => this.setState({
      searchResults: result
    }))

   }
     updatePlaylistName (name){
 this.setState ({
  playlistName: name
 })
}
  removeTrack (track) {
    const newPlaylistTrack = this.state.playlistTracks.filter(trck => trck.id !== track.id);
    this.setState({
      playlistTracks: newPlaylistTrack
    })

  }


  savePlaylist () {
    const trackUris = this.state.playlistTracks.map(track => track.uri)
    Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackUris).then(() => {
    this.setState({
    playlistName: "New Playlist",
    playlistTracks: []
  })
 })
 }
  


  
  addTrack (track) {
    if (this.state.playlistTracks.find(trackIn => track.id === trackIn.id)) {
      return
    }
    this.setState ({
      playlistTracks: [...this.state.playlistTracks, track]
    })
  }
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
       <div className="App">
         <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} onAdd={this.addTrack} isRemoval={false} />
            <Playlist playlistName={this.state.playlistName} playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks} isRemoval={true} onRemove={this.removeTrack} onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName} onSave={this.savePlaylist} />
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

the spotify.js file :

```
let accessToken;
const clientId = "6a6a7e54106048e6b97cf938b75fce8e";
const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/";

const Spotify = {

    getAccessToken () {
        if (accessToken) {
            return accessToken;
        }

    const accessTokenInMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
    
    if (accessTokenInMatch && expiresInMatch ) {
        accessToken = accessTokenInMatch[1];
        const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1])
        window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
        window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
        return accessToken;
    } else {
        const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`
        window.location = accessUrl;
    }
    },
search (term) {
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();


        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
  headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
}).then(response => 

response.json()

).then(data => {
    if (!data.tracks) {
    return []
}
return data.tracks.items.map(track => ({
    id: track.id,
    name: track.name,
    artist:track.artists[0].name,
    album: track.album.name,
    uri:track.uri
    
}

)



},
 savePlaylist (name, trackUris) {
  if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
    return
  }  
  const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
  const headers = {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`};
  let userId;
  return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, {method:"GET" ,headers:headers}).then(response => response.json()).then(jsonResponse => {
    userId = jsonResponse.id;
    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/users/${userId}/playlists`, {method: "POST", headers: headers, body: JSON.stringify({name:name})}).then(response => response.json()).then(jsonResponse => {
        const playlistId = jsonResponse.id;
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/users/${userId}/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks`, {method: "POST", headers:headers, body: JSON.stringify({uris: trackUris})})
    })
  })
    
  
  
  }

}

export default Spotify;
```

this is the TrackList file :

```
import React from "react";
import "./TrackList.css";
import Track from "../Track/Track"

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
              {this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track track={track} key={track.id} onAdd={this.props.onAdd} isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval} onRemove={this.props.onRemove} />)}
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default TrackList;
```

this is the Track.js file :

```
import React from "react";
import "./Track.css";

class Track extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
        this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
    }
    removeTrack () {
        this.props.onRemove(this.props.track)
    }
    renderAction () {
        if (this.props.isRemoval) {
            return <button className="Track-action"  onClick={this.removeTrack} > - </button>
        } else {
            return <button className="Track-action"  onClick={this.addTrack} > + </button>
        }
    }
    addTrack () {
        this.props.onAdd(this.props.track)
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="Track">
                <div className="Track-information">
                  <h3> {this.props.track.name} </h3>
                  <p> {this.props.track.artist}  | {this.props.track.album}</p>
                  <audio>
                  <source src={this.props.track.previewSample} type="audio/ogg" />
                   <source src={this.props.track.previewSample}  type="audio/mpeg" />
                  </audio>
                </div>
               {this.renderAction()}
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Track;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

On your src> util > spotify.js
in the return where you have `id: track.id, name: track.name, artist: track.artists[0].name, album: track.album.name` add another line that says `preview: track.preview_url,` (don't forget the coma "," after the track.album.name).
Then on your src > Components > Track > track.js in the last return where you have the  and the

tags add a new audio tag like this: `<audio src= {props.track.preview} controls />` and then style it with your Track.css file.

Answer (score -3):

ok my friend i will make just the principale file so i will remind you what's the matter exactly i want to get a sample for each track i get from the Spotify API but i failed:
this is the spotify file to get the track from spotify api :

```
let accessToken;
const clientId = "6a6a7e54106048e6b97cf938b75fce8e";
const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/";

const Spotify = {

    getAccessToken () {
        if (accessToken) {
            return accessToken;
        }

    const accessTokenInMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
    
    if (accessTokenInMatch && expiresInMatch ) {
        accessToken = accessTokenInMatch[1];
        const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1])
        window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
        window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
        return accessToken;
    } else {
        const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`
        window.location = accessUrl;
    }
    },
search (term) {
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();


        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
  headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
}).then(response => 

response.json()

).then(data => {
    if (!data.tracks) {
    return []
}
return data.tracks.items.map(track => ({
    id: track.id,
    name: track.name,
    artist:track.artists[0].name,
    album: track.album.name,
    uri:track.uri
    
}

)



},
 savePlaylist (name, trackUris) {
  if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
    return
  }  
  const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
  const headers = {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`};
  let userId;
  return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, {method:"GET" ,headers:headers}).then(response => response.json()).then(jsonResponse => {
    userId = jsonResponse.id;
    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/users/${userId}/playlists`, {method: "POST", headers: headers, body: JSON.stringify({name:name})}).then(response => response.json()).then(jsonResponse => {
        const playlistId = jsonResponse.id;
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/users/${userId}/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks`, {method: "POST", headers:headers, body: JSON.stringify({uris: trackUris})})
    })
  })
    
  
  
  }

}

export default Spotify;
```

this is the track file :

`````
import React from "react";
import "./Track.css";

class Track extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
        this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
    }
    removeTrack () {
        this.props.onRemove(this.props.track)
    }
    renderAction () {
        if (this.props.isRemoval) {
            return <button className="Track-action"  onClick={this.removeTrack} > - </button>
        } else {
            return <button className="Track-action"  onClick={this.addTrack} > + </button>
        }
    }
    addTrack () {
        this.props.onAdd(this.props.track)
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="Track">
                <div className="Track-information">
                  <h3> {this.props.track.name} </h3>
                  <p> {this.props.track.artist}  | {this.props.track.album}</p>
                  <audio>
                  <source src={this.props.track.previewSample} type="audio/ogg" />
                   <source src={this.props.track.previewSample}  type="audio/mpeg" />
                  </audio>
                </div>
               {this.renderAction()}
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Track;
````*
this is the App file :
`````

import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import SearchResults from "../SearchResults/SearchResults";
import Playlist from "../Playlist/Playlist";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar/SearchBar";
import Spotify from "../../util/spotify";

class App extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
searchResults: [{name:"FirstSong", artist:"artistName", album:"album1", id:1}, {name:"secondSong", artist:"artistName", album:"album1", id:2},
{name:"thirdSong", artist:"artistName", album:"album1", id:3}],
playlistName: "My Playlist",
playlistTracks: [{name:"fourthSong", artist:"artistName2", album:"album1", id:4}, {name:"fifthSong", artist:"artistName2", album:"album1", id:5},
{name:"sixthSong", artist:"artistName2", album:"album1", id:6}],
}
this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
this.search = this.search.bind(this);
}

search (term) {
Spotify.search(term).then(result => this.setState({
searchResults: result
}))

}
updatePlaylistName (name){
this.setState ({
playlistName: name
})
}
removeTrack (track) {
const newPlaylistTrack = this.state.playlistTracks.filter(trck => trck.id !== track.id);
this.setState({
playlistTracks: newPlaylistTrack
})

}

savePlaylist () {
const trackUris = this.state.playlistTracks.map(track => track.uri)
Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackUris).then(() => {
this.setState({
playlistName: "New Playlist",
playlistTracks: []
})
})
}

addTrack (track) {
if (this.state.playlistTracks.find(trackIn => track.id === trackIn.id)) {
return
}
this.setState ({
playlistTracks: [...this.state.playlistTracks, track]
})
}
render() {
return (

## Jammming

)
}
}

export default App;

```
this is the spotify tracks api :
```

{
"artists" : {
"href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=MAROON+5+ANIMALS&offset=0&limit=1&type=artist",
"items" : [ ],
"limit" : 1,
"next" : null,
"offset" : 0,
"previous" : null,
"total" : 0
},
"tracks" : {
"href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=MAROON+5+-+ANIMALS&offset=0&limit=1&type=track",
"items" : [ {
"album" : {
"album_type" : "album",
"artists" : [ {
"external_urls" : {
"spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP"
},
"href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP",
"id" : "04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP",
"name" : "Maroon 5",
"type" : "artist",
"uri" : "spotify:artist:04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP"
} ],
"available_markets" : [ "CA", "MX", "US" ],
"external_urls" : {
"spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/2Auw0pTT6EcQdvHNimhLQI"
},
"href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2Auw0pTT6EcQdvHNimhLQI",
"id" : "2Auw0pTT6EcQdvHNimhLQI",
"images" : [ {
"height" : 640,
"url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/4c23a82f33b034795a0fbc67af559420c8cb4928",
"width" : 640
}, {
"height" : 300,
"url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/44b0e6423240ed25f36f351ae043f68bb2ca3446",
"width" : 300
}, {
"height" : 64,
"url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/2e8ff05c6f96006130bbc64ef0b42b402252ace8",
"width" : 64
} ],
"name" : "V",
"type" : "album",
"uri" : "spotify:album:2Auw0pTT6EcQdvHNimhLQI"
},
"artists" : [ {
"external_urls" : {
"spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP"
},
"href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP",
"id" : "04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP",
"name" : "Maroon 5",
"type" : "artist",
"uri" : "spotify:artist:04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP"
} ],
"available_markets" : [ "CA", "MX", "US" ],
"disc_number" : 1,
"duration_ms" : 231012,
"explicit" : false,
"external_ids" : {
"isrc" : "USUM71409576"
},
"external_urls" : {
"spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/2bL2gyO6kBdLkNSkxXNh6x"
},
"href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2bL2gyO6kBdLkNSkxXNh6x",
"id" : "2bL2gyO6kBdLkNSkxXNh6x",
"name" : "Animals",
"popularity" : 69,
"preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/5dcd99cf811094408dcfc1befe014495d786dab5",
"track_number" : 2,
"type" : "track",
"uri" : "spotify:track:2bL2gyO6kBdLkNSkxXNh6x"
} ],
"limit" : 1,
"next" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=MAROON+5+-+ANIMALS&offset=1&limit=1&type=track",
"offset" : 0,
"previous" : null,
"total" : 99
}
}